# import multiple images Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, import

How can I import multiple images for one product in magento 1.7.0.2 :

[image]

I am adding images under /media/import this work fine for one image but i am not able to import multiple images, I tried using comma and semi colon(;) :

/image1.jpg,/image2.jpg and /image1.jpg;/image2.jpg

This gives error image path does not exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be mistaken, but I do not believe that the importer allows you to assign multiple images to a single product. A possible workaround I would try would be to have multiple line items per import, with precicely the same data **apart from** the image file, which you can then assign differently per line item, which Magento will then assign.

Not the tidiest solution, but worth a shot.

Comment: thanks for idea that worked .. duplicating a row in csv file keeping everything same except image.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use Magmi, see http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Upload your csv, I have 3 images per product, fill the first row with details and leave the second and third row blank apart from the colums as above.